# Cannot properly convert HTML body to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Visual Studio 2022. ASP.NET Web app. .NET Framework 4.8

Well, the problem is quite self-explanatory. I have a ready website done in HTML, CSS using Bootstrap and some JS, what I want to do is to convert it to an ASP.NET Web app.
The first problems that I've got are the following: Can't seem to load the bundles. Cannot load the .cshtml file that contains the header. When trying to start the project, the main body appears, as if It hasn't been applied any CSS over it.

What I've done so fast:
Installed the required NuGet packages, including `AspNet.Web.Optimization`.

In `Global.asax.cs` added the following code:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

In `RouteConfig.cs`, I've added bundles like that:

```
   public static class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js/js").Include(
                "~/Vendor/js/main.js"));
        }
```

The `Vendor` file contains the features not added via NuGet.

`_ViewStart.cshtml` looks the following way:

```
@{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

In the `_Layout.cshtml', the styles are called in the head part, like:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap/css")
```

And the scripts are called below the footer(which doesn't work as well) part, like:

```
@Scripts.Render("~bundles/bootstrap/js")
```

Calling of the header is done in the `body` part, like that:

```
<!--Header-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light shadow sticky-top p-0">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/_MenuBar.cshtml")
    </nav>
```

The main body is called via the `@RenderBody()` method.

The `_MenuBar.csthml` file contains only the code related to the header, and the `Index.cshtml` contains that code:

```
@model dynamic

@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

and then the part, that contains the main body.

The site is supposed to look like that ( with alot more below it, but for the sake of explaining, that should be enough so far ) :[image: Expected result]

But now, it looks like that: [image: Actual result]

What I should've done different to make it work?

Comment: This looks like it is a simple as your CSS and maybe JS files not being loaded properly. Try opening the Dev Console in the browser and check if they have been loaded. If they haven't, they tend to pop up as an error in the console on Chrome. If they haven't loaded then you know that in your bundle config, something isn't right. I have dealt with something similar a few years back and this was the problem. The file paths can be tricky sometimes. I'm not sure what causes this, but sometimes your file paths need the `~` and sometimes you need to remove it to make it work.

Comment: But why won't any of the headr ellements appears? Do I call the file in wrong way?

Comment: I just realized that it looks like you are setting the `Layout = null;` in the `Index.cshtml file`. Try removing that line. The Layout file should contain all of your headers, footers, even your `<head>` tag that contains all of your css tags. So if you set it to null on that page, then you will not have any of the headers or footers rendered.

Comment: I've changed it to `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 ViewBag.Title = "Home";`, and it seems to work, plus to that, seems like I've managed to make my header appear and CSS apply, for the CSS to work, I had to create another file in the `App_Start` folder, named `BundleConfig.cs`, where i've put all my bundles, ain't sure if THAT's the thing that helped, but it seems to work, although, the colors are kinda off and the images in the main body won't load at all, which is strange

Comment: Are your images hosted with your asp.net site, or are they resources that you are loading from other web locations? If they are on your site, then you might have to play with the src paths. They don't always play nicely when you take a site built without using a backend framework to using asp.net or .net core or whatever. That's where I would start trying to fix the images.

Comment: @JG222 the images are hosted on my device, I've tried to fix it by doing the following:
Insert the code, and then look, what does visual studio say about that, and it said:
`No file called X in the path Y`, so I added the sourse files in that way, so that notification won't appear, but it still didn't help. Guess I have to play around it a little more

Comment: Seems like adding `~/Vendor/` before any image source helps to fix that problem, although it is quite tidious

Comment: Yeah that's frustrating, but I'm glad you've got it working. Good Luck!